# I keep getting the "ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: OverflowError: int too long to convert" error

Tags: memory

This is my code which i've followed from a tutorial

```py
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

rwm = ReadWriteMemory()

process = rwm.get_process_by_name("mspaint.exe")
process.open()
#0x7FF767E70000 
#"mspaint.exe"+000EA350

baseadress = 0x7FF767E70000 + 0xEA350

pointer1 = process.get_pointer(baseadress, offsets=[0x58, 0x8, 0x0, 0x20, 0x120, 0x8, 0x80, 0x30, 0x70, 0x10])

while True:
    value = process.read(pointer1)
    print(value)
```

I tried to shorten zeroes at the end of the "baseadress", but it doesn't work. I don't know what else to try